# Save inside any folder instead in Desktop

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, httpresponse

Code:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=pdfpage.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

The above code I used to allow a user of my web application to save a PDF generated on the server on his own device. The file is saving in as `pdfpage.pdf` on the desktop but I need to save this file in any folder. For example in `E:\PDFs\pdfpage.pdf`

Comment: Your code just adds HTTP headers rather than saving anything. The code, which performs saving needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was wrong. I corrected part of it. Part of it is still wrong: you claim that the PDF is saved on the desktop. That may be true when you test it, but that is not true in general. For instance: if I would use your app, the PDF would be saved in the Downloads folder *as defined in the settings of my browser.*

**There is no way you can define the download folder of a browser on the client by setting a parameter on the server.**

There are some very simple reasons that explain that what you're asking for is impossible:

1. The server has no idea of the file structure on the client. For instance: there is no `E:` disk on my computer, so if you'd define the download folder as `E:\PDFs\pdfpage.pdf`, your web application wouldn't work.
2. It would be a serious security issue if a server were able to read the entire folder structure of the client machine in order to detect where to save a PDF file.

You are asking for something that is to be configured on the client side, in the browser of the end user. This can not be configured on the server side. For instance: I use Chrome, Firefox and Edge on my machine. I have defined different download folders for these different browsers. If I'd use your web app in one browser, it would download the PDF in a different folder depending on the browser I use.